# Javascript form script not working on mobile (but perfect on dekstop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello so i have a JS issue and because i don't know much about it i've got no idea where to start in order to fix it !

I currently have a script that runs on a django web page, that hides incompatible options from two picklists; using a reference dictionnary.

The script works pretty well on desktop; **but not at all when i view the page from a mobile device.** (all the options are still visible...!)

Any ideas would be rgeatly appreciated !

**Here is the** [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5gm7x7e/1/)

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
<label for="id_tasks">Tasks:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="id_tasks" name="task">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Tie-job: Front-tie Marker</option>
    <option value="2">Tie-job: Scrapmachine support trackman</option>
    <option value="3">Tie-job: Plate Thrower</option>
    <option value="4">Tie-job: New-tie Marker</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
<label for="id_craft">Craft:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_craft" name="craft">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Senior Engineer</option>
    <option value="2">Roadmaster</option>
    <option value="3">Foreman</option>
    <option value="4">Assistant Foreman</option>
    <option value="5">Electrical Welder EA</option>
    <option value="6">Oxygen Welder OA</option>
    <option value="7">Railway Machine Operator (RMO)</option>
    <option value="8">Truck Driver (Type A, B or C)</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_craft option:not([value=0])").hide();
});


$("#id_tasks").change(function() {

  $("#id_craft").val("0");
  $("#id_craft option:not([value=0])").hide();
  var compIds = {
    1: [1, 2],
    2: [3, 4],
    3: [4, 5],
    4: [6, 7]
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < compIds[$("#id_tasks").val()].length; i++) {

    $("#id_craft option[value=" + compIds[$("#id_tasks").val()][i] + "]").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: How is this question different to the one you've [deleted 5 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520742/javascript-form-script-not-working-on-mobile-but-perfect-on-dekstop) ago?

Comment: Which devices/browsers are you testing in?

Comment: Works fine on Chrome and Firefox (but not on IE...); doesn't work on iOS (Safari) though ...

Comment: @Andreas : its the same as the edited version with the JS Fiddle, that wasn't there from the start !

Comment: So there's no reason for deleting and re-posting the same question other than pushing it back to the top?

Answer (score 0):

I presume there's a problem on iOS with recognizing your selector `option:not([value=0])`.

You should check http://caniuse.com/ to see if that method is supported in mobile devices, and if not, you can use a `.forEach()` loop instead.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; i tried doing a $("#id_craft option").hide();
      $("#id_craft option[0]").show(); but it doesn't seem to work either on mobile...

Comment: @Malcoolm Oh, in that case `hide()` is probably not working because the list of options aren't really being displayed on the HTML page, but on the operating system's UI. Have you tried removing it from the DOM entirely via `remove()`? https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: but then how do i put the options back?

Comment: If you need to put them back, then you can save them into an array, call `detach()` to take them out of the DOM (https://api.jquery.com/detach/) and then `appendTo()` to add them back later (https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/). It's a bit more involved that a simple `show()` and `hide()` but it's the only quick solution that works across operating systems.